# Can't figure out how to modify Azure Loadbalancer BackEndPool with Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-resource-manager

I have a load balancer configure in Azure (ARM) and I have 2 back end pools: prod, stage. Through the GUI, when I want to promote a staging server to production, I remove it from the stage pool and place it in the prod pool. I'm very confused about how this all works because when I provision the stack, I first provision the load balancer and when I provision the NIC that the VM will attach to, I place that NIC in the backend pool I want. However, when I want to move the VM to another pool, I no longer do that at the NIC level. I have to do that at the load balancer.

Using the Python SDK, I am able to see which NIC is in the backend pool if I query the LB but there seems to be no way to modify that. I can also query the NIC and see which backend pool it's associated with but again, no way to modify (from what I can tell). This is what I have so far:

```
# Create the client
network_client = azure.mgmt.network.NetworkResourceProviderClient(creds)

# Get all LBs
lbs = network_client.load_balancers

# select LB in question
lb = lbs.get(group,'cc-lb01')

# get all pools
pools = lb.load_balancer.backend_address_pools

# set variables for pools
prod = pools[0]
stage = pools[1]
```

The output of print(dir(stage)) is:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_backend_ip_configurations', '_etag', '_id', '_load_balancing_rules', '_name', '_provisioning_state', 'backend_ip_configurations', 'etag', 'id', 'load_balancing_rules', 'name', 'provisioning_state']
```

So I thought I was onto something when I saw 'backend_ip_configurations'. When look at my options there (by typing this):

```
print(stage.backend_ip_configurations)
```

It returns an array of objects:

```
[<azure.mgmt.network.networkresourceprovider.ResourceId object at 0x03C9C090>]
```

There is only 1 item in that array so I set that item to a variable:

```
beip = stage.backend_ip_configurations[0].id
```

and when I see what my options are with 'beip', this is where I dead end.

```
/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/app-green04-nic/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1
```

The output of print(dir(beip)) is:

```
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

I cannot figure out how to see what NICs are in the backend pool and modify that pool other than through the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this video and GitHub repo that demonstrates handling modifying the Pool membership via REST and Python.

In the end, it's about getting to the proper json that get's sent via updates

https://mix.office.com/watch/f4cvoa3cnfoe

Note in the following the `/src` path has the Python version

[https://github.com/cicorias/AzureLoadbalancedPoolUpdate](https://github.com/cicorias/AzureLoadbalancedPoolUpdater)r

### Approach and order

You actually go at this from the NIC direction, and not the Load Balancer. The update (PUT) is against the "NIC".

The general Order is

1. Get the VM's and their NICs
2. Get the NIC's relationship to the backend pool
3. Remove by leaving `loadBalancerBackendAddressPools` empty
4. Add by putting the resource ID into the `loadBalancerBackendAddressPools' array

The creation of a REST request, via PUT, is here.

```
def build_request(vm_object, nic_object, load_balancer=None):
"""
:param vm_object : azure.mgmt.compute.VirtualMachine
:param nic_object : azure.mgmt.network.networkresourceprovider.NetworkInterface
:param load_balancer : azure.mgmt.network.LoadBalancer
:return: dict
"""
if load_balancer == None:
    backend_pool = []
else:
    backend_pool = [{ 'id' : load_balancer.load_balancer.backend_address_pools[0].id }]

request = {
    'properties': {
        'virtualMachine' : {
            'id' : vm_object.virtual_machine.id
            },
        'ipConfigurations' : [{ #may have to build by hand
            'properties' : {
                'loadBalancerBackendAddressPools' : backend_pool,
                'subnet' : {
                    'id' :  nic_object.ip_configurations[0].subnet.id
                    }
                },
            'name' : nic_object.ip_configurations[0].name,
            'id' : nic_object.ip_configurations[0].id
             }]
        },
    'id' : nic_object.id,
    'name' : nic_object.name,
    'location' : vm_object.virtual_machine.location,
    'type' : 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces'
    }


return request
```

Answer (score 1):

Same question has been answered on github by Hugues at below link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/471

Quote the answer here in case any other community members have a similar inquiry:

> Resource references are currently inconvenient to follow, because
>   there's no get() that allow you to fetch using a reference id. So you
>   need to parse the names of the resources that make up the id.
>
> In this case, you need to parse the resource id to get the names
>   'myresourcegroup', 'app-green04-nic' and 'ipconfig1'. With these,
>   you'll be able to access the NIC with 
>   network_client.network_interfaces.get('myresourcegroup,
>   'app-green04-nic') .
>
> Looking at LoadBalancerOperations, it looks like you should be able to
>   do a get(), modify the contents of the
>   load_balancer.backend_address_pools[0].backend_ip_configurations by
>   adding/modifying/removing ResourceId objects, and then call
>   create_or_update() with the modified LoadBalancer object.
>
> Obtaining a resource id to create a ResourceId is easy, no need to
>   build the string yourself, you can usually just call a get() method
>   and Azure will populate and return the id for you. For example, to get
>   the resource id for a NIC configuration:
>
> ```
> result = network_client.network_interfaces.get('myresourcegroup', 'app-green04-nic')
> result.network_interface.ip_configurations[0].name
> #ipconfig1
> result.network_interface.ip_configurations[0].id
> #/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/app-green04-nic/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1
> ```
>
> You can't index by name on those collections, so you'll need to
>   iterate to find the one you are looking for.

Should you have any further concern, please feel free to let us know.